# Django figure out which template rendered the view you are seeing

Tags: python, django, url, view, django-templates

So, I've recently inherited a large code base that is fairly obfuscated. When I navigate a page on my local machine is there any way to determine which template/view is actually being called to create the view that I'm seeing at that moment?

I would like to get a better idea of where certain parts of the page are actually coming from, but the project is so large and disorganized that going through present templates is simply not feasible.

Is there any nice way to get around this? Worth mentioning that the defined urls all seem to be poorly written, obfuscated regex, (not to mention incredibly long) so direct examination of the urls file is not extremely feasible.

When I try to run resolve on the url of the page I'm trying to view I get a 404, and I'm not really sure where to progress from there, since the page clearly works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnaly I use this : https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

> The Django Debug Toolbar is a configurable set of panels that display
>   various debug information about the current request/response and when
>   clicked, display more details about the panel's content.
>
> Currently, the following panels have been written and are working:
>
> ```
> Django version
> Request timer
> A list of settings in settings.py
> Common HTTP headers
> GET/POST/cookie/session variable display
> Templates and context used, and their template paths
> SQL queries including time to execute and links to EXPLAIN each query
> List of signals, their args and receivers
> Logging output via Python's built-in logging, or via the logbook module
> ```
>
> There is also one Django management command currently:
>
> ```
> debugsqlshell: Outputs the SQL that gets executed as you work in the Python interactive shell. (See example below)
> ```
>
> If you have ideas for other panels please let us know.
>
> ```
> Note: The Debug Toolbar only works on Django 1.3 and newer.
> ```

0 code to add, only a few minor changes to settings.py
You will get what you want and even more.

Comment: Oh god, this is wonderful! Got up and running in no time and this does exactly what I want!